Log4j is logging logs with wrong (lower) level
Having the root logger with INFO level:
rootLogger.level=INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref=ConsoleAppender

and a specific logger with DEBUG level:
logger.kinesis.name=org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer
logger.kinesis.level=DEBUG

How comes that there are such lines logged at DEBUG level:
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer [] - stream: 

?
From the documentation each logger will inherit de level from it's parent, but the parent for
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer

is the root logger, that has INFO level.
Here is the entire configuration:
rootLogger.level=INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref=ConsoleAppender

# Log all infos to the console
appender.console.name=ConsoleAppender
appender.console.type=CONSOLE
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level=${sys:console.log.level:-ALL}


logger.kinesis.consumer.name=org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer
logger.kinesis.consumer.level=DEBUG

P.S.Just to be more visual, that's how I see it should work

Can you add your entire configuration to the question? Do you use global filters (which override the level check on loggers)?

@PiotrP.Karwasz
Added the configuration

You are right about how a log hierarchy works. Your example of log event does not follow the pattern you set up in your configuration file, which suggests that either another log4j2.* file is used or another logging backend (e.g. Logback).

@PiotrP.Karwasz There is no another logging backend for sure because the DEBUG logs started to pop-up after the modification  of the log4j file
